# EF Seed Called When IIS Start

Tags: ef-code-first

We use EF Code First seed method for deploy our project parameters. When we restart iis in anytime, the seed method working again and updates datas. Why it called again?

Our configuration file:

```
  public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(FastVContext context)
    {

        #region Menu And Sub Menu

        context.MenuItems.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
           new MenuItem()
           {
               Id = 1,
               MenuName = "Özet",
               Priority = 100,
               cssClass = "fa fa-tachometer",
               Controller = "Home",
               PageURL = "/"

           },
             new MenuItem()
             {
                 Id = 2,
                 MenuName = "Genel Ayarlar",
                 Priority = 60,
                 cssClass = "fa fa-cogs",
                 Controller = null

             },
```

}

And our context file

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

```
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

.
.
}

Comment: does this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You can use the attribute disableDatabaseInitialization="false" to skip the initializer, which is where the data seeding and DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges takes place.

```
<contexts>
  <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity" disableDatabaseInitialization="false">
    <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```